# How can I prevent code duplication in my fancyBox initialization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancyBox 2.1.5 and I have 3 selectors to fit videos and images in different ways. They only differ very slightly, so there's a lot of duplicated code.

Here's what that looks like:

```
// Fit video content to display area, ignoring title text.
$('.fitVideo').fancybox({
    helpers: {

        // Enable the media helper to better handle video.
        media: true,

        // Put comments within the white border.
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    // Do not use this because it tries to fit title text as well.
    fitToView: false,

    // Prevent the introduction of black bars when resized for mobile.
    aspectRatio: true,

    // Restrict content to the display dimensions.
    maxWidth: "100%",
    maxHeight: "100%",

    // Change the title keyword to 'caption' to avoid title text in tooltips.
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    },

    // Override the default iframe dimensions with manually set dimensions.
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
        this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
    }
});

// Fit image content to display area, ignoring title text.
$('.fitImage').fancybox({
    helpers: {

        // Put comments within the white border.
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    // Do not use this because it tries to fit title text as well.
    fitToView: false,

    // Restrict content to the display dimensions.
    maxWidth: "100%",
    maxHeight: "100%",

    // Change the title keyword to 'caption' to avoid title text in tooltips.
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});

// Only fit image content to display width; content extends beyond the bottom of the page.
$('.fitImageWidth').fancybox({
    helpers: {

        // Put comments within the white border.
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    // Do not use this because it tries to fit title text as well.
    fitToView: false,

    // Only restrict content to the display width.
    maxWidth: "100%",

    // Change the title keyword to 'caption' to avoid title text in tooltips.
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```

They all share the same values for `title`, `type`, `fitToView`, `maxWidth`, and `beforeLoad`, so I was hoping I could maybe place those properties within the `$('.fancybox')` catch-all and then have small selectors with only unique properties that "stack" on top of these defaults.

That might be the wrong approach altogether, though... So what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting different classes, as demonstrated in my initial post, actually splits those items into different fancyBox groups, even if they all share the same `data-fancybox-group` value.

That means you wouldn't be able to mix videos and images in a single group, or even images with different screen-fit parameters, using the approach above. Luckily, this pushed me toward a much more elegant solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

        beforeLoad: function() {

            var elem = $(this.element);

            if (elem.hasClass("video")) {
                this.width  = elem.data("width");
                this.height = elem.data("height");
            }

            if (elem.hasClass("tall")) {
                this.maxHeight = 9999;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

I've switched back to selecting ALL `fancybox` elements (so everything can be properly grouped), then using the fancyBox `beforeLoad` callback to test if a certain class exists on the selected element and changing properties appropriately. So far it's worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this way:

```
//Save your default settings
var fancySettings = {
    helpers: {
       // Put comments within the white border.
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    // Do not use this because it tries to fit title text as well.
    fitToView: false,

    // Only restrict content to the display width.
    maxWidth: "100%",

    // Change the title keyword to 'caption' to avoid title text in tooltips.
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
}

//Apply defaults
$('.fitImage, .fitImageWidth').fancybox(fancySettings );
//For any modification just extend it from the new object which will override the properties if they are existing.
$('.fitVideo').fancybox($.extend({}, fancySettings ,{helpers:{media: true}});
```

Comment: Thanks PSL, your suggestion does work, but it turned out my whole approach actually broke the way fancyBox groups items. I'm not sure what StackOverflow etiquette dictates in this situation, but with my question being specifically fancyBox related, I'm inclined to post my final working approach as the answer. Correct me if this is wrong!

Comment: @calbar Surely you should post if you think that is better suited to your question... And you can accept it as well (I guess after some hours or so.)